# Setting NAD 1983 EPSG 102631 in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I was able to find the right coordinate system online [NAD 1983 Alaska](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102631/)

But now I don't know what to do.  I can't find the coordinate system on QGIS.  When I choose the one I think is correct it warps everything.

I have a lot of shp files that were made in the coordinate system NAD 1983 EPSG 102631 which does not show when I use filter and try to set the CRS. When I load the shp files into my project and the CRS says custom everything seems fine. But when I set a CRS for my project it goes crazy.  I want to use these shp files with other data and it seems I need to convert or at least get something sorted out before I can use this data with other data.

It seems I need to custom set the proj strings... I've been reading the manual and I haven't found how to do this yet.

Comment: You can't just **set** a prjection in qgis. You need to reproject it from a source CRS to a target (your alaska projection). Use the "Save As" dialog for instance.

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far. Please add details about the data and your desired results.

Comment: In QGIS 2.01, the projection is called `NAD_1983_StatePlane_Alaska_1_FIPS_5001_Feet EPSG:102631`. If you use QGIS 1.8.0, you have to set up a custom projection for it.

Comment: If you know projection, in QGIS you can paste in "srs description" the [proj4 code](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102631/proj4/) of the [projection link](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102631/) who you are speaking about.

Comment: There's no such code defined in the EPSG Geodetic Parameter Registry, it's an ESRI defined code

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the CRS filter for EPSG:26931, from http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/26931/

There are duplicate ESRI codes for the State Plane Coordinate systems on spatial-reference.org that have a different format .prj strings. The equivalent EPSG codes are different, and they are whats in QGIS.

[image]

Comment: No, not really the same. The ESRI projection is in feet, the one you propose is in metres.